# memory game star rating error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, html, css

The function below is used to get the number of counts or clicks in a memory game

```
function countmoves(){
    movecount++; //the increment of clicks
    moveNumber.innerHTML = movecount <= 1 ? movecount+" " + "Move" : movecount +" "+ "Moves";

    if (movecount == 12){
        let stars = document.querySelectorAll('.fa fa-star.checked');
        stars.classList.remove("checked");//this part of the code fails

    }
}
```

The number of clicks as per the game is working but i want to remove the class 'checked' if the Count of clicks equal 2 as stated in the if condition

Comment: Looks like `stars` is a node list and not a single node. You might need to iterate over the `stars` nodelist and perform the operation on each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let stars = document.querySelectorAll('.fa .fa-star.checked');
```

`querySelectorAll()` function will return array

You should try:

```
let stars = document.querySelectorAll('.fa .fa-star.checked')[0];// or give specific index of element...
```

Or

```js
let stars = document.querySelectorAll('.fa .fa-star.checked');
stars.forEach(function(item,index){ 
     stars[index].classList.remove("checked");
});
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```css
.checked{
    background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="fa">
    <div class="fa-star checked">A</div>
</div>
<div class="fa">
    <div class="fa-star checked">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried this but it says classlist is undefined now

Comment: @NAND i think you selecting elements by wrong way. Try to get idea from my updated snippet.